# Swipe MudTabs on mobile

Tags: mudblazor

I am trying to view `<MudTabs/>` component on mobile and I want to scroll through the tabs by swiping. The only way to scroll through at the moment is by tapping on the arrows.

I tried doing css below but no luck.

```
.horizontal-scroll {
    height: 7vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```